# Почему происходит ошибка с ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main/urls'?

Tags: python, django

Хз что тут как описать, что вылезает в терминале, но вот такая ошибка все время. В Django пишу, файлов много.

Comment: Хз чо на это ответить, данных мало.

Comment: Хз что сказать, у тебя, походу, ошибка в коде

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем. Нужно больше конкретики, информации и минимальный пример.

Comment: Скорее всего (гадание на кофейной гуще) вы импортируете в основной файл `urls.py` аналогичный файл приложения. По вашему пути `main/urls` нет такого модуля. Если это папка вашего приложения то его можно просто создать или удалить импорт в основном файле.